# How to keep the same precision in these two numpy array procedures?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, precision, multiplication

Using `f` and `x`,

```
In [173]: f
Out[173]: array(1387)

In [174]: x
Out[174]: array([ 20404266.1330007])
```

`exponent1` and `exponent2` are computed and compared.

`exponent1` is computed as follows:

```
In [183]: exponent1 = 1j * 2 * np.pi * f[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * x
```

`exponent2` is computed as follows:

```
In [186]: exponent2 = np.array([[[ 1.+0.j]]])

In [187]: exponent2 *= x[np.newaxis, ...]

In [188]: exponent2 *= f[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis]

In [192]: exponent2 *= 1j * 2 * np.pi
```

`exponent1` and `exponent2` are close:

```
In [195]: np.allclose(exponent1, exponent2)
Out[195]: True
```

But their exponentials are not:

```
In [196]: np.allclose(np.exp(exponent1), np.exp(exponent2))
Out[196]: False
```

Is there a way to make their exponentials close as well?  I would like the latter to be closer to the former because

```
    In [198]: np.allclose(np.exp(exponent1), np.exp(1j * 2 * np.pi * 1387 * 20404266.1330007))
Out[198]: True
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is finite precision and, as presented, there is nothing you can do about it.

In your problem you are calculating 2*pi*f*x.  Since this appears in a function with period 2*pi, the complex exponential, the only significant part of f*x are the digits after the decimal point.  In other words, the information in f*x is only contained in the values in the interval [0,1) so we can think of really needing to calculate f*x modulo 1.0.

If we look at the values you provide we find
f*x = 28300717126.4719(73)
where I have put the "extra" digits, beyond the first 15, in parenthesis. (Roughly we expect about 15 digits of precision, you can be more careful with this if you care but this is sufficient to get the point across.)  We thus see that we are only calculating f*x to 4 significant digits.

If we now compare the values calculated in your question we find

```
exponent1 = 177818650031.694(37)
exponent2 = 177818650031.694(4)
```

where I again have used parenthesis for the extra digits.  We see these values agree exactly as we expected them to.  For the exponential version we are interested in these values modulo 2*pi,

```
exponent1%(2*pi) = 2.965(4796216371864)
exponent2%(2*pi) = 2.965(5101392153114)
```

where now the parenthesis are for the extra digits beyond the 4 significant ones we expected.  Again, perfectly good agreement *to the level we can expect* . We **cannot** do better unless x and f are calculated in such a way to not have all these extra, unnecessary digits "wasting" our precision.

Comment: I suppose my original question was intended to be about why exponent1 and exponent2 are any different at all since I started off with the same f and x.  But I kind of see your point above, that they all have the same number of digits (17) and they agree to the same decimal (3).  How is 'modulo 2*pi' related to the exponential function though?  I don't understand.  Can I not replace it with 'modulo any number' and  the results will still agree to the same decimal?

Comment: exp(1j*theta) = cos(theta) + 1j*sin(theta) and cos(theta+2*pi*n) = cos(theta), same for sin(), for n an integer.  Thus we only need theta modulo 2*pi.